# Как вычесть n часов из DateTime?

Tags: php, ооп

Как из `DateTime('now')` вычесть, например, 32 часа?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Методом [modify](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php)

```
$now = DateTime("NOW");
$now->modify("-32 hour");
echo $now->format("ВАШ ФОРМАТ");
```

Answer (score 3):

Вычитаем один день 8 часов, - не уверен что вычитание 32-х часов отработает корректно:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1DT8H'));
```

Описание и примеры можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php).

Comment: Лучше использовать [DateTime::sub()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php) :)